# eclipse CDT issue on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

On one of my Mac box, for simple Hello Word C++ program, there are such compile error, other Macs I am working on are ok. Using even the same version of Eclipse CDT 64-bit Mars.

Posted error and Hello Word program, does anyone have any hints? Thanks.

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Test1.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Attach error from g++ of command line,

g++ Test1.cpp
Test1.cpp:9:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
Test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test1.cpp:13: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
Test1.cpp:13: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: If anyone have good thoughts, it will be great. :)

Comment: can you compile it from the terminal? e.g. `g++ -o hello hello.cpp` and then run it? `./hello` If so, can you get detailed output of the commands that eclipse is running?

Comment: @Bill, good idea, posted error output from g++. I am using Mac OSX.

Comment: Have you installed xcode?

Comment: @Bill, yes, I think it is installed by default in Mac OS -- I mean I do not do anything additional. I do not use XCode since it is for Object C only? I prefer standard C++, which I think I should use Eclipse CDT? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: XCode does not come by default on the Mac, you have to go to the app store. Installing XCode also gives you C/C++ compilers, libraries, headers, useful tools like git, etc...

Comment: @Bill, I have Xcode installed. Is it for Object C only?

Comment: No, it includes C, C++, ObjC, and Swift. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315386/i-cannot-compile-helloworld-cpp-with-eclipse-cdt-on-mac?rq=1 The person switched to an older version of Eclipse. Although I wouldn't waste my time w/Eclipse for C++ development. Also, when compiling your program in the Terminal, you should `cd` to the directory where your program is and then try to compile it.

Comment: @Bill, thanks and tried XCode works good to me. If you could summarize your reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, if whether you're developing in C, C++ or Objective C on the Mac, you probably just want to use XCode.

Not sure what Eclipse was doing, but (see link in comments) earlier versions of Eclipse might work where later ones will not.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the great answer!

Comment: @LinMa Glad you're going now. Good luck!